# Android Rating Bar unable to set decimal values

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am trying to set the rating bar's inital rating to a float value. But the output is always completely filled stars! I have no idea why this is happening.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ratingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
    ratingBar = ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1));
    ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("3.5"));
    ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1))
            .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);

}
```

This is the rating bar:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it by programattically like this

```
ratingBar = ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1));
ratingBar.setStepSize(0.5f);
ratingBar.ratingBar.setNumStars(5);
ratingBar.ratingBar.setMax(5);
ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("3.5"));
```

Comment: No, not working. You can try it if you want. I guess that's how the Rating Bar is desgined

Comment: Try to change the filling color of the rating bar so that you will able to get difference.

Answer (score 0):

You just remove the toolbar in your project. I think there is some issue in toolbar. I tried as follows, it works

```
ratingBar = ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1));
    ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("3.6"));
    ratingBar = ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the stepSize="0.5". You should change it to 0.1.

Comment: why should I change it?

Comment: we need to set the decimal step size with the interval of 0.1, if you give the  0.5 interval some times it gets round of. did you try with stepSize="0.1" ???